# Is there an extension in Visual studio code to get actually installed versions of packages from package.json?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

In WebStorm there's a great way to know which version of a package actually installed in your node_modules, by ctrl+hovering on the package name in package.json. Is there an extension with a similar funtionality in VS code? Tried this one https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ldd-vs-code.better-package-json
But it seems abandoned

Comment: Not really an answer, but you can see the actually installed version with `npm ls <package name>`

Comment: You can write your own if you like, just parsing `yarn.lock` or `package-lock.config` isn't that hard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [VersionLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pflannery.vscode-versionlens) extension can do this.

To get it to automatically show the versions like WebStorm:

1. Install the extension.
2. In the extension list, click the gear and choose **Extension settings**.
3. Scroll to the bottom and check the box for **Show on startup**.

Then restart VSCode.  It won't show the versions instantly because it has to analyze the dependencies, but they will show up after awhile.

Answer (score 3):

You can also consider using [Package Json Upgrade](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=codeandstuff.package-json-upgrade). It doesn't load your screen with information, e.g., if you have the latest then it will not show anything. Also, upgrades are colored according to severity (in the screenshot it is an old project that I did not upgrade for a long time and just upgraded  `Axios` and `react-scripts` to demonstrate how it shows when you have the latest version.

[image]